# Connecting two macbook pros and a windows laptop device to external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, display, thunderbolt, kvm

I have a brand new Windows 10 laptop that I use for wok. I also have a macbook pro from 2012 and a new macbook pro with thunderbolt 3 ports.

I want to connect at least the windows laptop with the new macbook (and maybe the old one). My goal is to use my dell monitor, logitech bluetooth keyboard (which has a bluetooth receiver) and the logitech mosue (which also has a bluetooth receive that is plugged in).

What type of device(s) do I need to connect them? I would prefer something that makes it easy to switch between laptops.

Comment: Without providing more information about the Windows 10 computer and what ports it has, and the Dell monitor and what ports it has theres no way to give a helpful answer on this front. You could just move the HDMI cable from one device to another.

Answer (score 1):

Many modern Logitech keyboards, indeed many modern Bluetooth keyboards and mice include support for multiple pairings, you should check if yours do and use this, otherwise you will be limited in what swapping you can do because you'll need to disconnect and reconnect on each device and that will require trackpad/mouse input on both other devices.

The hardware solution to this is a KVM but that won't work with a Bluetooth keyboard, the software solution might work but will depend on one machine being consistently there is using something like Synergy Desktop app.